# How to convert query result object into string in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following code in my controller:

```
    $sql = "SELECT MAX(roll) FROM student WHERE department = '".$this->db->escape_str($sdata['department'])."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Nothing wrong with it. I'm getting my expected value.

However, when I try to use this value somewhere else as a string, like the following:

```
   $rolltext = substr($query->result(), 9);
   print_r($rolltext);
   die();
```

And then run the application in localhost, I get the following error:

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Warning

    Message: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I know that the variable $rolltext is getting query result in the form of an array, instead of string, which is incorrect in terms of syntax of the `substr()` function. That's why I'm getting this error. My question is: How can I convert this query result into a string and perform my substr() operations in the subsequent lines? I didn't find a specific solution/guideline for such case in the CodeIgniter user guide, that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
 $sql = "SELECT MAX(roll) as maxroll FROM student WHERE department = '".$this->db->escape_str($sdata['department'])."'";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql);
 //$result = $query->result();  //  returns the query result as an array of objects
 $result = $query->row(); // returns a single result row
 $rolltext = substr( $result->maxroll, 9);
```

> Note:
>
> The syntax for accessing values from query resultset is :
>
> *$result->fieldname;*
>
> where *$result* is the resultset and *fieldname* is the name of the
>   field you want the output of in your query.

Comment: Change `result()` to `row()`

Comment: @Jenz Bull's eye! Not just the correct answer, but also a concise and gist explanation. You're simply awesome, coz you just made my day!